# How to write problem just after numbering without any vertical space

Tags: exam

In documentclass exam,

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question

\begin{equation*}
 \mbox{Let } f(x,y)= \left \{
    \begin{array}{ll}
\frac{x}{y} &   \mbox{ if }  (x,y) \neq (0,0)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\\
  0                     & \mbox{ otherwise. }~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\\
    \end{array}
  \right.
\end{equation*}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

is it possible to write the problem just after numbering without any verticle space? That is Let should start just after 1, without any vspace.

Comment: As you may know, it would be easy for us to help you if you provide us with a MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never, ever, type those `~`’s. What is the purpose???

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question
Let
\begin{equation*}
f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
           \dfrac{x}{y} & \text{if }  (x,y) \neq (0,0), \\
           0           & \text{otherwise.}
         \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Then \dots
\question
Let $f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
                x/y & \text{if }  (x,y) \neq (0,0), \\
                0   & \text{otherwise.}
              \end{cases}$
Then \dots
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: cases]